# Move camera and update its orbitControl in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to change the camera position in the code and update the controller base on it.

Easily, I run:

```
camera.position.x = 20;
controls.update();
```

but this doesn't work at all !

`controls.update()` reset the camera position !

take [webgl_decals](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals) as example, just declare the controller out of init() function, (so that you can call it in console), in console, run:

```
camera.position.x = 20;
controls.update();
```

the camera position will reset and will not change its position !

Is this the right way of of changing the camera position ?

any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, i was trying to update the camera by changing `camera.position` , instead I changed `controls.target` and it works !

Please take into consideration updating the controller by `controls.update()` after making this change.

Comment: Please provide a full example as it's not clear what "after making this change" means.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `OrbitControls` and you want to set the camera position programmatically, you can do so by using the following pattern:

```
controls.enabled = false;

camera.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
camera.lookAt( controls.target );

controls.enabled = true;
```

three.js r.97

Comment: using controls again reset the camera position, i.e the camera position will change but when i try to use the controls after that it will reset the camera position :(